# How Can I Destructure an Argument With a Default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I run the following snippet in Chrome, it runs perfectly:

```
(({foo}={}) => {console.log(foo);})({foo: 'baz'});
// logs "baz"
```

However, if I run that same snippet in Node I get a:

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

... despite the fact that I ran Node with both the default and destructuring harmony parameters:

```
nodejs --harmony  --harmony_destructuring --harmony_default_parameters
```

So, my question is, what magic incantation does Node require to process this (perfectly valid, as far as I can tell) ES6 statement?

Comment: I'm not sure the feature is functional yet (even in harmony) for use with arrow functions. It works just fine when using the non-arrow function syntax -- `(function({ foo } = {}) { console.log(foo); }({ foo: 'baz' }));`. I'm on node `v5.5.0`, by the way.

Comment: There is a reason it's behind a flag and not enabled by default :P

Comment: Full destructuring support is introduced in [V8 4.9](http://v8project.blogspot.com/2016/01/v8-release-49.html). It is expected to be incorporated into Node 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dvlsg suggested, this is simply a bug in the experimental implementation of these Node features.

However, as @estus suggested, and as indicated by the Node developers themselves [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6081), the soon-to-be-released new version of Node will not only fix this problem, it will also roll the bulk of the ES6 functionality directly in to Node (ie. no more `node --harmony_whatever`).